# Azure CLI - VSTS - Yaml - Only the first line of the script seems to be executed

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I have the following yaml build defintion for vsts which is supposed to create an azure resource group and deploy resources.
However, while the resource group is created, no resources are deployed. As if the second line of the script is ignored.
Note that if I run the deployment script line alone (when the resource group exists), the resources are deployed.

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySub (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
        az group create -l westeurope -n TestRG
        az group deployment create -g TestRG --mode Incremental --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @azuredeploy.parameters.json
    workingDirectory: Test
```

Here the build output:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: AzureCLI
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure CLI
Description  : Run a Shell or Batch script with Azure CLI commands against an azure subscription
Version      : 1.130.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827160)
==============================================================================
az group deployment create -g TestRG --mode Incremental --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @azuredeploy.parameters.json
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" login --service-principal -u ******** -p ******** --tenant ********"
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Test",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "********",
    "user": {
      "name": "********",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account set --subscription Test"
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\azureclitaskscript1520242163645.bat""
D:\a\1\s\Swoon>az group create -l westeurope -n TestRG 
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/TestRG",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "managedBy": null,
  "name": "TestRG",
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
  },
  "tags": null
}
******************************************************************************
Finishing: AzureCLI
******************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using window agent, so you need to append call in front of the multiple commands to execute all of them.

For example:

```
call az group create -l westeurope -n TestRG
call az group deployment create -g TestRG --mode Incremental --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

Comment: Tks for this answer as I never saw any mentions to "call" in any ms docs. Moreover, when I create the build definition for a windows agent visually and click on "view yaml", there is no "call" keyword.